# How to understand this query about divide operator in INSIDE SQL Server 2008 querying?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm following the book "Inside Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Querying". On Page 95,
the author explains divide operator with an example; Basically it returns all customers for whom every employee from the USA has handled at least one order.

The query is like so.

```
USE InsideTSQL2008;

SELECT custid 
FROM Sales.Customers AS C
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                  FROM HR.Employees AS E
                  WHERE country = N'USA'
                    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                                    FROM Sales.Orders AS O
                                    WHERE O.custid = C.custid
                                      AND O.empid = E.empid));
```

First, the two parts below got all the orders which are handled by the USA employees. Correct?

```
(SELECT * 
 FROM HR.Employees AS E
 WHERE country = N'USA'

SELECT * 
FROM Sales.Orders AS O
WHERE O.custid = C.custid
  AND O.empid = E.empid);
```

If so, why does he use `NOT EXISTS` to filter out these orders?

The goal of this query is to find all the customers with at least one order handled by all USA employees, it filters out the right ones, as I see.

Second, I can't see anything in this query related to divide operator. How does this query come with dividing?

Comment: The subquery will return all records that do not have the same `custid` as the outer. Then the outer says give me every record that is not in the subquery, essentially resulting in the ones with the same custid. No idea about divider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First, the two parts below got all the orders which are handled by the USA employees. Correct?

No. The subquery contains a reference to the outermost query through the `C` name and cannot be evaluated by itself. Additionally, clearly `SELECT * FROM HR.Employees` gets you employees, not orders.

The complete subquery is

```
SELECT * FROM HR.Employees AS E
WHERE country = N'USA'
AND NOT EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM Sales.Orders AS O
WHERE O.custid = C.custid
AND O.empid = E.empid)
```

which means "select the USA employees which do not have an order for customer `C`".

In general, "all X for which every Y has Z" can be rewritten as "all X for which no Y exists for which not Z". In your case,

> all customers for whom every employee from the USA has handled at least one order

can be rewritten as "all customers for whom there is no employee from the USA which has not handled any order".

That's why the whole thing is put in `NOT EXISTS`.

> Second, I can't see anything in this query related to divide operator. How does this query come with dividing?

It's about the division that's part of relational algebra, not simple division of numbers. It's called division because it's the inverse of the Cartesian product (i.e. the inverse of a cross join).

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Division_.28.C3.B7.29 for more info.

Comment: Thanks very much, hvd! Now this query is getting much clear, and so does the dividing. Now I'm trying to write a new query with the logic "all X for which every Y has Z". If I simply delete the two "NOT", the result is not correct. The reason might be "WHERE EXISTS" cannot represent "All X for sth", it may represent there maybe an X for sth, am I right? If so, may you pls give me a tip to handle it with that logic?

Comment: @Ranger22 You're right that that's the reason. In general, I wouldn't recommend writing it in that form, simply because it would be harder to read by being unconventional, but if you want to experiment anyway, the `ALL` keyword might work for that: `select * from X where 1 = all(select case when Z then 1 else 0 end from Y)`.

Comment: thanks again! I just started learning sql server. And I find it is kind of difficult for me to get the logic for solving a problem, and then make the query based on the logic. Basically I don't really know how to start learn SQL querying. If you can give me some suggestions, like how to start, books, practice stuff or something, that's really appreciated!

Comment: @Ranger22 I've been thinking, but I got most of my SQL basics from a first-year database course at university. Some universities make their course materials freely accessible online, they may be worth a try. I can't recommend any one in particular though.